# Identity Db Context Get Null In Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created API in .net 7.0, I have EF core with `IdentityDbContext`.
Problem is when I am going to find user by user manager as below get null exception.

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValueFromSqlBufferInternal\[T\](SqlBuffer data, \_SqlMetaData metaData, Boolean isAsync)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValueInternal\[T\](Int32 i, Boolean isAsync)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValue\[T\](Int32 i)
```

I have tried to get user in login action.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{

    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

    if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
        var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        var authClaims = new List<Claim>
        {
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
           new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        };

        foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
        {
            authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        }
        var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
        claims: authClaims,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
        return Ok(new
        {
            token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
            expiration = token.ValidTo
        });
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Comment: Do you add DB_context in the program.cs?

Comment: yes added. 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, IdentityRole>()
                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: hmm... are you saying that `model.UserName` is not `null` here? which line is throwing the exception, and have you tried debugging it?

Comment: yes, i have already tried to debug it through exception on             var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
where model.UserName is not null.

Comment: Have you passed dbcontext in constructor?

Comment: yes passed it,  and initialize in constructor.

Comment: please check this 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45759

Comment: @Nahid I have different issue i have the value in NormalizedUserName  but getting null even try to get single or default user getting same error.

Comment: It looks like the query for the user is returning a null value for an integer, and integers cannot be null unless you explicitly make it nullable. If you are sure the user exists and is being retrieved, check what integer values are null in the user data table.

Answer (score 0):

I it resolved, i have model related error, it have not null define model but i have removed it from database, so it create problem to retrieve data.